# Is there anything like Thorns in DS2?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I was doing some PVP in the Luna Belltower last night and I was completely baffled. Every time I hit this person, I lost a quarter of my health to what looked like lightning. I got a backstab, and died from it.

Is there anything like Thorns from Blizzard games in Dark Souls 2? Something that does damage to anyone attacking the player. Gear, spells(probably a miracle based on the lighning), or even weapons are fine. I've looked around, but from what I've seen, a lot of resources aren't fully in place yet.

Comment: As 5pike said, likely a cheater.  Dark Souls 1 and 2 are riddled with them and the developers seem to do nothing.

Comment: Can you modify your question to include what 'Thorns from Blizzard' is and what it does for people who are not familiar with it?

Comment: There you go! Quick and dirty, but I think it gets the basic premise across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that would be similar to it would be the [Ring of Thorns](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Ring+of+Thorns#.U2uKpPl_t8E) or the Pyromancy [Immolation](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Immolation#.U2uKbvl_t8E), but both do not work as you described.

When the Ring of Thorns procs (it doesn't work on every hit, only on a %, based on the ring level) it shoots out some darts (see this [video at 0:58](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9YFz1TCojvI&t=0m57s)).

Immolation sets the caster on fire, so you would have seen it.

What probably happened - you encountered a cheater (likely) or lag

Comment: Immolation is not a retaliation like Thorns, it's an offensive spell that damages at all times as long as you're close to the opponent.

Comment: True, but I'm still including it. It might not function like thorns, but it's like an aura that does damage simply because you stand to near to an enemy (like Smelter Demon).

Comment: I may have been lag, as I did notice a small amount of rubber-banding. Though I didn't think it was that much of an issue. Is cheating even possible on the 360? I don't understand how that would work, perhaps I should open another question for it.

Comment: @Telestia - Yes cheating is possible on the 360.

Answer (score 4):

After much discussion and your alternative question about cheating, I have experienced what you experienced *multiple times* and I **do not think he was cheating**.

As others have mentioned there is a ring (the Ring of Thorns) that shoots thorns out at a certain damage threshold. What I have not heard anyone else mention is that **there is a second ring that creates an AOE explosion at the point of impact a couple seconds later**, the [Old Sun Ring.](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Old+Sun+Ring#.U20IDvldVfA) This ring can be stacked with the thorns ring and its behavior would describe exactly what you described. A backstab on someone wearing both of these rings with little physical defense and little fire defense could easily one hit someone with mid to low health.

I do not believe he was cheating, in the countless hours that I have played this game I have not once run into a cheater, not to say that they are not out there. There is currently not a game save editor for DSII for the 360 (you mentioned you were playing on 360 in the other question), I would put it at an extremely low probability that he was a cheater and an extremely high probability he had both rings on and you got hit with damage threshold recoil.

Comment: Thank you for adding to the answers! This is quite informative, and sheds new light on what happened to me.

Comment: But there is a game save editor for [DS2 Xbox360](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ZHWmrWQs3I)

Comment: If Telestias description is exact, it was a cheater, because there currently is no spell/shield/ring that retaliates with lightning damage on every hit (as he described). ... Stupid "5 minute edit" rule

Comment: @5pike From the video and the comments, that is the beginning of a save editor, but a farcry from being usable. I never intended to say that a save editor was not going to be created, just there was not one publicly available at the time this question was asked. As for the description of the ring. You are correct that there is no ring that produces a lightning retaliation, but that was not my point. My point was that I believe what they are describing is actually the Old Sun Ring explosions, with fire mistaken for lightning.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is something quite similar, it's called the [Ring of Thorns](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Ring+of+Thorns).

There's still doubts as to how it works exactly (the damage amount given to the attacker), based on the amount on damage taken, basic user stats, etc.

I haven't actually used it to know if the retaliation looks like lightning,  but I hope this helps.