# How do people cheat in Dark Souls 2 on the 360?

Tags: xbox-360, dark-souls-2

I asked [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/167277/is-there-anything-like-thorns-in-ds2) earlier and the answers informed me of cheating on the 360!

> I was doing some PVP in the Luna Belltower last night and I was completely baffled. Every time I hit this person, I lost a quarter of my health to what looked like lightning. I got a backstab, and died from it.

This is kind of a big question, so I'll break it up into parts.

1. What benefits can this confer to the cheater? This would be useful to know for the next part.
2. How can a legitimate player counter this? Is it possible to defeat these people, or is it just better to try and get as close to a bonfire as possible to minimize losses?

Thanks!

Comment: You should invite @5Pike to this question, as he was the one to make the claim on your other thread that cheating is possible on the 360.

Comment: Number 4 is explicitly off-topic; we don't handle questions about finding information from devs.  The rest...is going to be iffy.  Cheating in multiplayer is something we don't help with, but perhaps we can help with remedies to said cheating.

Comment: For #4 you would be better off looking at their [official forums](http://forums.bandainamcogames.com/forumdisplay.php?14-Dark-Souls).  If you do not find a post that matches your experience, then you can be the one to mention it.

Comment: I've edited my question based on @Frank's suggestion.

Comment: Killing a hacker is possible by knocking them off a ledge.

Comment: I would suggest including the behavior going on in this question.  Otherwise, anyone coming to this question will need to go to your other one before this makes any sense.

Comment: @Batophobia, I've added that as well.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the tips on how to ask a good question. I'm glad we got that all sorted out!

Comment: To answer your (now removed) question on how it's possible to cheat: In order to be able to cheat, you need to have a modded console, so that you can run homebrew and then you need to find and install a trainer (cheat program). Another method would be to extract the save from the console and edit it to whatever you want (console doesn't need to be modded for this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cheaters can be handled by leaving
That's all you can do, save your game and leave

Report them on Xbox, file a complaint and give them bad player rep
File a complaint - Xbox actually have to look into these but the user will have to have several complaints for action to be taken(by different users for the same reason.)

Bad player rep - Starts on their Xbox profile decrease and they get connected to other players who have rep like they do, this also stops them finding you in matchmaking. 
(This apply's globally, not just to the Dark Souls 2.)

Try not let them get to you that's the main thing, if you get annoyed then the modifier has done what he wanted to do.

Benefit to the modifier is, he gets to have power over you, because basically you are powerless to them, this is what drives them.